# tomcat virtual directory mapping for static file browsing as resource not working for japanese filename

Tags: tomcat, weblogic

Below is the configuration i have as tomcat context conf

```
<Context docBase="<dir_path>" path="/resources">
<Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext"
          allowLinking="true"  />
```

This config is able to get resources with english language as file name ex: test.txt
But it's not working for japanese filename ex:- おきかえGP_TEST.txt . I guess it is not working for any non English locale.

Same thing can be reproducible using weblogic virtual-directory-mapping in weblogic.xml

```
<virtual-directory-mapping>
    <local-path><dir_path></local-path>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you already solve it, however this might helps you.

Add these attributes at your port Connecter.(at server.xml)

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
```

My settings is below.(I'm using 8400 port)

```
<Connector port="8400" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="9400" 
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
```